# Gulp - Getting Sass errors through to html

Tags: sass, gulp

I've come from Grunt to Gulp. Good so far but i can't seem to get the Sass errors to show on the site. Curently it stops the whole gulp task and i only get an error in Terminal

With Grunt the errors appreared immediately on the local site in a css content property. I liked this much better, much easier to use. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy:"dummy.com"
    });

    gulp.watch("craft/web/sass/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("craft/templates/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("craft/web/sass/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("craft/web/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: grunt-sass and gulp sass behave differently as far as error handling goes. grunt-sass outputs the result to the file regardless if it errors or not, whereas gulp-sass throws a PluginError. IMO the Gulp method is better as it errors out on the task, and doesn't output a bad file.If you want the grunt-sass behaviour you're likely going to have to fork the project and make the modification yourself.

Comment: Ok i can work around that, thanks.